# clarification about blackberry code signing and application signing

Tags: blackberry

I am new to blackberry development and i am confused about the signing terms. I understand that if I use protected apis in my code then i need to get my code signed by blackberry in order for my code to work on a real device. Is that also the same as signing my application as in the way a J2ME app is signed so that it is "trusted"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to apply for a set of BlackBerry signing keys from RIM, they are free, see here: https://www.blackberry.com/SignedKeys/

Note the drop down, if you are developing a java application set it to 'BlackBerry Smartphone Code Signing Key'

You will receive emailed instructions on how to import the keys into the IDE you are using for development.

You will also receive three (3) further emails, each containing a different signing key, you will need to import all 3 keys into your development environment.  I have mentioned this, because this is were many people have fallen in this signing issue, by only importing the key from one of these 3 emails.

Comment: I have done all of that and I have signed the COD files of my app. I just wanted to know if that also means my app becomes a "trusted" app in the same way a j2me/android app is trusted when signed with a signature cert/key. The reason i ask this is because how does someone know that the app hasn't been tampered with? Because from my understanding the blackberry code signing does just that.. allows my app to access restricted apis on the device and nothing more

Comment: For the actual mechanics of what code signing does beyond allowing your app. access to restricted APIs, and identifying you as the developer if those APIs are abused, may I suggest that you pose your question here: http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/bd-p/java_dev where it 'may' get picked up and answered by one of the BlackBerry Advisors who visit the forum.